Show support information to user telebot
in one telegram bot, when you click the "support" button, a window with support contact information pops up
A button to contact support doesn't look like a url button, it looks like something with callback data. How to make the same in my bot?

I usually implement it in the following way:
sup_mk = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

sup_btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="contact support", url="t.me/mysupport")

sup_mk.add(sup_btn)

In that bot, some other way is used. A button to contact support doesn't look like a url button, it looks like something with callback data. How to make the same in my bot?
